# Unable to copy using cp command in AIX

Tags: aix

I am trying to copy directories recursively using `cp -R` command in AIX, however certain directories(related to ITDS and DB2 Instance) like *SQLT0000.0/SQL00123.DAT*, *SQLT0000.0/SQL00123.DAT*, and *SQLT0000.0/SQL00123.INX* are not getting copied and give error:

> Invalid argument

Below is the output of truss command:

execve("/usr/bin/cp", 0x2FF22B9c, 0x20013678)    argc: 3

sbrk(0x0000000)                                = 0x30002430

vmget info(0x2FF22510, 8, 16)                  = 0

sbrk(0x0000000)                                = 0x30002430

_libc_sbrk(0x0000000)                          = 0x30002430

getuidx(2)                                     = 0

umask(0)                                       = 18

umask(18)                                      = 0

statx("/appl/ciam/test", ox2FF22A40. 175, 020) = 0

statx("SQL00027.INX", 0xFF22000, 176, 020)     = 0

statx("/appl/ciam/test/SQL00027.INX", 0x2FF22938, 176, 020) Err#2 ENOENT

kopen ("SQL00027.INX", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)      ERR#22 EINVAl

kwrite(2, "c p", 2)                            = 2

kwrite(2, ":", 2)                              = 2

kwrite(2, " S Q L 0 0 0 2 7 , INX", 12)        = 12

kwrite(2, " : ", 2)                            = 2

kwrite(2, "invalid argu" , 16)                 = 16

kwrite(2, "\n", 1)                             = 1

access("/appl/ciam/test/SQL00027.INX", )       = Err#2 ENOENT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy one of this files individually, to find out if the problem is file-specific. If so, check if the file-path containts something problematic, like a symlink to a not-readable directory.

Also you can try 'truss' to find out the system-call that fails (open/read/write etc) -- not for beginners though.

Comment: Yes i have tried to copy that particular files. some file SQL00xyz.INX or SQL00xyz.DAT files are copied and some giving invalid argument error

Comment: I have updated my question with the output of the truss command you suggested.  Could you please take a look and see if there is something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have tried to copy that particular files. some file SQL00xyz.INX or  SQL00xyz.DAT files are copied and some giving invalid argument error

Comment: What command did you try? My guess:

    cp SQL00027.INX /appl/cia /test/SQL00027.INX

the problem occured during opening the input file. Are there other processes using this file?

    fuser SQL00027.INX